# Cannot access "this" in bind callback in backbone.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So here is my simple popover module again. It can be assigned to a view which will trigger the popover:

```
function(app) {

  var Popover = app.module();

  Popover.Views.Default = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'popover',
    initialize: function() {
      this.visible = true;
      this.render();
    },
    setReference: function(elm) {
      this.reference = elm;
      this.reference.bind('click', this.toggle);
    },
    beforeRender: function() {
      this.content = this.$el.find('.popover');
    },
    show: function() {
      //this.visible = true;
    },
    hide: function() {
      //this.visible = false;
    },
    toggle: function() {
      this.visible ? this.hide() : this.show();
    }
  });

  // Required, return the module for AMD compliance.
  return Popover;
});
```

This is how I set the popover:

```
Main.Views.Start = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "main/start",
    serialize: function() {
      return { model: this.model };
    },        
    initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },
    beforeRender: function(){
      this.popover = new Popover.Views.Default();
      this.insertView(this.popover);
    },
    afterRender: function() {
      this.popover.setReference(this.$el.find('.member'));
    }
});
```

I want the toggle function of popover to be called when `this.$el.find('.member')` is clicked. This works fine. However inside the toggle function I cannot access "this" from popover object, instead "this" contains the html from its parent. So I get an error in toggle function:

```
TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'show'
```

Any ideas how to get access to the actuall popover object inside toggle callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, `functions` create new context for `this`. And with jQuery, when you bind an events, jQuery assign `this` to the current element. That's why you lost the context. So what can you do?

First, you can manually assign the this value:

```
this.reference.bind('click', _.bind(this.toggle, this));
```

Second, the best way is to manage events in the Backbone View `event` object:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click element": "toggle"
  }
  // ...rest of your code...
});
```

Comment: How would your second example would look like when you apply my code? The first example works, but second looks more the backbone way

Comment: Well, your code seems to have organizational issues making the second method hard to apply. You should really consider refactoring your code so that this way is easier to integrate with your solution. Basically, the `setReference` method and the way it's used really don't look good.

Comment: The underlying idea is that your view shouldn't listen for events happening on DOM elements outside himself. If it should respond to an event happening elsewhere (in another view), then you should use a global event manager to communicate between the two view without creating hard dependencies on each other. This pattern is implement in every major Backbone FW (Backbone Boilerplate with `app`, Marionnette with `Vent`, and even raw with `Backbone` object being a global event manager).

Comment: Hmm but what if a method is referring to another method in the same object? I can't write an event listener for this because nothing in the DOM is being touched.

Comment: @Trip Simple function call?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Ah right that's what I thought. Turns out.. I was binding an addEventListener to window.. which means I had to additionally pass `this` or `bind(this)`.. Sort of off topic. Haha sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the function to the Backbone object, for example in the `initialize` method with:

```
initialize: function() {
      this.visible = true;
      _.bindAll(this, 'toggle');
      this.render();
}
```

Comment: Because this change the function behavior in an unexpected way (because `this` can't be reassigned manually). Let's just say this isn't maintainable.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Check the `underscore` source code, `bindAll` uses `bind` internally

Comment: Yes of course, but it changes the object method to the new function; not just a function value.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Ooohh now I see it! You are right, it is changing the method in the object. Something to take into consideration! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.reference.bind('click', this.toggle, this);  // 3rd param is a context
```

or

```
_.bindAll(this, "toggle");
```

...but the first is better.

From BackboneJS docs:

> Binding "this"  Perhaps the single most common JavaScript "gotcha" is the
>   fact that when you pass a function as a callback, its value for this
>   is lost. With Backbone, when dealing with events and callbacks, you'll
>   often find it useful to rely on _.bind and _.bindAll from
>   Underscore.js.
>
> When binding callbacks to Backbone events, you can choose to pass an
>   optional third argument to specify the this that will be used when the
>   callback is later invoked.